# undefined method 'x' for #<

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have defined in `analysis_result.rb` this:

```
 def total_matches
 ...
 end
```

and I am trying to use it in a view `_rable_row.haml` like this:

```
- if analysis.results.total_matches != 0
  = link_to analysis.title, analysis, class: 'js-toggle', data: { href: "loading-#{analysis.id}" }
- elsif analysis.results.total_matches == 0
  = render partial: 'partials/shared/empty'
```

but I'm getting `undefined method 'total_matches' for #<Mongoid::Criteria:`

Can someone tell me why is this happening?

Comment: `@analysis` is nil. Thats the problem

Comment: @Pavan okay, that I understand. I changed to analysis.results. could you check my question now?

Answer (score -1):

The error *`undefined method 'total_matches'`* arises because `total_matches` cannot be called directly on the `results` array, it is an attribute of objects present inside the results array.  I.e. you are trying to call an attribute of an object on array of objects, instead of on the object itself.